# How to change language to English in Oppo A59s?

Tags: languages, oppo-coloros

All the RAM result are in Chinese, and I can't read it. I have an OPPO A59s running Android version 5.1, and a ColorOS version 3.0. All output is really difficult to understand and operate. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try going into the settings, and search for language.

Unfortunately, that version of Android and colorOS is very old and outdated. Try and see if you can update it to a newer version.

Some oppo apps may of not been translated into languages other than Chinese.